# SpringBoot Multiple AutoConfiguration exclusions defined at startup

Tags: spring-boot

I work on a corporate Spring Boot extension that autoconfigures its own RabbitMQ clients. This extension (a starter) replaces the Spring Boot RabbitAutoConfiguration.

I know there are many ways to disable the RabbitAutoConfiguration :

- in **each** Application (main) class with @EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = RabbitAutoConfiguration.class) or @SpringBootApplication(exclude = RabbitAutoConfiguration.class)
- in the application.properties or yml file (externalized or within the jar), with spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.amqp.RabbitAutoConfiguration

I wonder if there is a way that the **presence** of my new starter disables the Spring Boot RabbitAutoConfiguration.

I tried some dirty things, such as putting an application.properties with the exclude property in the corporate starter module, but as Spring Boot only reads one in the classpath, it can be easily overriden by one used in a client application. I do not want to impose some restrictions.

I do not like the idea of each application adding the same exclusion one way or the other (properties or annotation).

Any ideas ?

**EDIT**

I need to configure several RabbitMQ `ConnectionFactory` and `RestTemplate` within the same application.

Comment: If you manually configur rabbit, the auto configuration automatically backs off... No need to exclude it.

Comment: @M.Deinum This is not the behavior I get because there are two RabbitTemplate in the configuration. The RabbitAutoConfiguration does not work with more than one.

Comment: There are a lot of `@COnditionalOnMissingBean` annotation on the configuration. So if you already added a `RabbitTemplate` and `Connection` the configuration shouldn't do anything.

Comment: @M. Dienum : you are absolutely right. See my comments below the first answer. I may be in a particular case in which conditions are not evaluated as I would like to. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to truly replace the standard `RabbitAutoConfiguration` by yours, you just need to add `@AutoconfigureBefore(RabbitAutoConfiguration.class)` on your own auto-configuration to teach Spring Boot to process yours before the standard one.

If it is a replacement, yours will register beans that the standard auto-configuration will detect and it will back-off the same way as if you would have defined them manually.

Having said that, why are you doing this? I'd rather *complement* the existing auto-configuration rather than replacing the standard one. Is there a problem with the standard one? If so, we'd love to hear about it and adapt the code so that you don't have to fully replace it.

Comment: Well the configuration, despite the conditionals, still requires a single `ConnectionFactory` as you apparently have multiple that fails. You can mark one of them as `@Primary` to resolve that issue.

Comment: @M. Deinum : you are right _when it is possible to annotate the @Bean declaration of one `ConnectionFactory`_. The problem is that connection factories are registered _dynamically_ by a home made `BeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessor`(BDRPP) at startup : one instance of this BDRPP is declared in the Spring Config for each RestTemplate needed by the application. The `@Primary` annotation can not be dynamically defined while registering a bean. However, the simplest way to solve this would be an explicit instruction in my own autoconfigurer that deactivate the `RabbitAutoConfiguration` completely

Comment: You can tell a `BeanDefinition` if it is the primary... So you could mark the first as primary.

Comment: No it should not. We do have `@ConditionalOnSingleCandidate` for that thing I believe. We're going deep in comments here, chat or gitter perhaps? All I meant to say is that, you shouldn't have to disable an auto-configuration if you replace it with your own code, be it user configuration or an auto-configuration that kicks in before. Certain areas of Spring Boot require primary beans but that must remain a corner case.